# django Autocomplete-light how to choose a specific method from a mode

Tags: django-autocomplete-light

I am new at django and autocomplete-light. I try to get a different fields of the model from autocomplete-light, but it always return the same field. And the reason is because def in the Model defined one field. So I created another def, but can not make autocomplete-light to call that specific def. Here is my code.

```
models.py:

class Item(models.Model):    
...
serial_number=models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)
barcode=models.CharField(max_length=25, unique=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.serial_number

    def bar(self):
        return self.barcode
```

.......

```
autocomplete_light_registry.py

autocomplete_light.register(Item, 
    name='AutocompleteItemserial',
    search_fields=['serial_number'],
)

autocomplete_light.register(Item, 
    name='AutocompleteItembarcode',
    search_fields=['barcode'],
)
```

Here is the issue: when I try to get the barcodes from the autocomplete-light, it returns serial_numbers. No matter what I try to get from the Item model, it always returns the serial number. I really appreciate for the answers. Thank you.
Just in case, here is the form.py

```
forms.py

class ItemForm(forms.ModelForm):
widgets = {
    'serial_number': autocomplete_light.TextWidget('AutocompleteItemserial'),
    'barcode': autocomplete_light.TextWidget('AutocompleteItembarcode'),
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Although this is an old post but as I just faced the same issue therefore I am sharing my solution.

The reason autocomplete is returning `serial_number` is because django-autocomplete-light uses the __unicode__ method of the model to show the results. In your `AutocompleteItembarcode` all that is being done is autocomplete-light is searching by `barcode` field of `Item`.

Try the following.

```
In app/autocomplete_light_registry.py

from django.utils.encoding import force_text

class ItemAutocomplete(autocomplete_light.AutocompleteModelBase):
search_fields = ['serial_number']
model = Item
choices = Item.objects.all()

def choice_label(self, choice):
    """
    Return the human-readable representation of a choice. 
    """

    barcode = Item.objects.get(pk=self.choice_value(choice)).barcode
    return force_text(barcode)

autocomplete_light.register(ItemAutocomplete)
```

For more help you can have a look at the [source code](http://django-autocomplete-light.readthedocs.org/en/latest/_modules/autocomplete_light/autocomplete/base.html#AutocompleteInterface.choices_for_values).